# Picker control binds to index and not to tag

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, watchos

I am having an issue where my Picker control is binding to the index of the item and not to the value specified in the tag. I am using WatchOS.

```
Picker("Hour:", selection: $hour) {
                ForEach((twentyFourHour ?  0 : 1)..<(twentyFourHour ?  24 : 13)) {
                    Text(String(format: twentyFourHour ? "%02d" : "%d", $0))
                        .tag($0)
                }
            }
```

when I

```
print("p: \(period) hr: \(hr) hour: \(hour)")
```

I get

```
p: am hr: 0 hour: 0
```

I have tested by adding an arbitrary value to the tag value and it still seems to be binding to the index. I have tried using the "{ i in " syntax too with the same result.

I am basing this off the Apple documentation:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/picker?changes=latest_minor

Comment: Your question is pretty vague. When exactly in the code do you print this out? What is `period`? What is `hr`?  What do you expect it to output?

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/64859699/12299030?

Comment: @Asperi: No, this is not a type issue, as you can see the index type and the value type are the same. Again if you read the question it states: Picker is binding to the index and not to the value.

Comment: Would you provide standalone minimal reproducible example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is the loop does not consider primitive types as identifiable. As such you need to explicitly define the identifier as being the primitive value as such:

```
Picker("Hour:", selection: $hour) {
            ForEach((twentyFourHour ?  0 : 1)..<(twentyFourHour ?  24 : 13), id:\.self) {
                Text(String(format: twentyFourHour ? "%02d" : "%d", $0))
                    .tag($0)
            }
        }
```

the key addition being:

```
id:\.self
```